# Array input not adding up. -- total += scoreArray[i];

Tags: java

This section of code below for some reason is not taking each array item made and adding them together.
I stepped through the debugger and the array items are being created and incremented but the `total += scoreArray[i];`does not seem to be adding up the numbers that have been input. Instead, I am just getting just the 1st input divided by the array length as the final output

```
    public double getAverage()
    {
        double total = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++)
            total += scoreArray[i];

        return (total / scoreArray.length);
    }
```

Full Code

```
package driver;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScores
{
    private double[] scoreArray;

    public TestScores(double[] test) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        scoreArray = new double[test.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
        {
            if (test[i] < 0 || test[i] > 100)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Test scores must have a value less than 100 and greater than 0.");
            else
                scoreArray[i] = test[i];
        }
    }

    public double getAverage()
    {
        double total = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++)
            total += scoreArray[i];

        return (total / scoreArray.length);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  
        int score = 0;
        int scores = 0;

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter number of test scores: ");
        score = userInput.nextInt();

        double[] scoreArray = new double[score];

        for (int i = 0; i <= score - 1; i++)
        {    
            System.out.print("Enter test score " + (i + 1)+ ": ");
            scoreArray[scores] = userInput.nextDouble();      
        }  

        TestScores testScore  = new TestScores(scoreArray);
        System.out.println(testScore.getAverage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two `scoreArray` ?

Comment: HAve you tried debugging your code to see what happens?

Comment: When you input the scores, you keep putting them in the same element. This us something the debugger would have caught. Or even a few well-placed print statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your loop of accepting user score with following:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= score - 1; i++)
{    
    System.out.print("Enter test score " + (i + 1)+ ": ");
    // scoreArray[scores] = userInput.nextDouble();  <-- value of scores is zero
    scoreArray[i] = userInput.nextDouble();      
}
```

You should use "i" instead of "scores" while populating scoreArray.       Currently you are populating your "scoreArray" with only last entered user input.